# Images not Loading from .json file for React Js

Tags: reactjs, image, webpack

guys I am fairly new to React Js, however I am working with a code that has been sent over and I need to edit for some images. So, I know the basics of changing, styling and just overall editting in React js, not that hard. But I am newbie when it comes to error messages or errors I can not see.

```
"dogs":{
    "text": "This is text",
    "src" : "img/dog.png"
}
```

Calling it in my app.js using:

```
let {text, src} = config.sections.information[title];
              return (
                <ImageSplit key={k} title={title} direction={dir} text={text} src={src} />)
```

So, as you can see in the code snippet above I use a .json file for the text and image. However, the images do not come up at all, and in the console i am getting the error message of:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I have looked online for a solution with using WebPack, and it wants me to use require() however, I get the error of 'no module found of 'image name''

Comment: I'm gonna ask the obvious. Does dog.png does exist inside the img folder?

Comment: It just means that the image at `img/dog.png` on your dev server isn't available at that path. Is it possibly under a different directory? Maybe a `static` folder, or something.

Comment: Yes, the images are located inside the img folder which is inside the static folder. However, I should have mentioned this in the post, but 2 out of 4 images are available but the rest are not. So all in all, some images are loading some are not

Comment: So a little update. The `dog.png` does not work in any situation, however the working images I had before `cat.png` works in _all_ cases. Anyone have a hunch of why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Image file should be relative to the .json file not the app.js. **Rookie move.**

With trying my best to find out exactly what went wrong, I came across nothing within the console, apart from the error message mentioned above.

So, I found out the issue I was having was based up my git repo not being up to date, so the live version of the app was working fine with the images but the client side was not. Pulling also did nothing, so what I done is I reinstalled WebPack, reset my .json file and made sure the images were relative to the .json file and not to the app.js. Rookie move on my part. Thank you for everyone who replied and tried to help.